# How to Give AWS Lambdas in Application Permission to Invoke each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an aws lambda application with two lambdas. I want to give one of the lambdas permission to invoke the other. I added this statement to the policy section for the lambda doing the invoking. (The actual statement has the correct account number, I just removed it when posting here)

```
        - Statement:
            - Sid: LambdaAllowLambda
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - lambda:InvokeFunction
                - lambda:InvokeAsync
              Resource: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxx:function:helpSlashCommand'
```

Here's the code that invokes the lambda

```
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const lambda = new Lambda();
            const params = {
                FunctionName: 'helpSlashCommand',
                InvocationType: 'Event',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({
                    body: req.body,
                    headers: req.headers
                })
            };
            lambda.invoke(params, err => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
```

I see the policy in the resource summary for the lambda
[image: policy]

When I call the lambda it fails to invoke the second lambda with this error.
[image: lambda error]

here are my resource configurations in template.yml

```
Resources:
  # Each Lambda function is defined by properties:
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction

  # Routes the Slash commands
  router:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: src/handlers/router.routerHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Description: Authorizes the request and routes to a slash command lambda.
      Policies:
        # Give lambda permission to get call lambda
        - Statement:
            - Sid: LambdaAllowLambda
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - lambda:InvokeFunction
                - lambda:InvokeAsync
              Resource: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:function:helpSlashCommand'
        # Give lambda permission to get item from waiting room
        - Statement:
            - Sid: DynamoDbAllowLambda
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - dynamodb:GetItem
              Resource: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:table/waiting-room'
        # Give Lambda basic execution Permission to the helloFromLambda
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Events:
        HttpPost:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: '/interaction-endpoint-url'
            Method: post

  # This is a Lambda function config associated with the source code: hello-from-lambda.js
  helpSlashCommand:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: helpSlashCommand
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: src/slash-commands/help.slashCommand
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Description: Authorizes the request and routes to a slash command lambda.
      Policies:
        # Give Lambda basic execution Permission
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

Any idea how I can manage these permissions from the template.yml file?

Comment: As the error message states there is a permission boundary in place. You need to figure out where that boundary comes from and whether you can change it or what your organizational policy regarding the boundary is.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks. i am using my own account logged in as a root user. is there a way to manage the permission boundary from the aws lambda application? The application is creating all the resources so it should be possible to do this from the configurations. I want to avoid any manual permission management as much as possible

Comment: What you are doing in your Lambda is already correct/enough. As @luk2302 mentioned, there is a permissions boundary that supersedes that. You have to remove or update that. As to how or why you have that boundary in our account, I do not know.

Comment: @NoelLlevares It looks like aws lambda applications come with an autogenerated boundary when the app is initially created that has permission to invoke the provided lambda. I don't see a way to update that autogenerated boundary when creating a new lambda in the project, but I manually updated the policy so that it allows the lambda to be invoked. I was hoping that could be managed by the application

Comment: How are you deploying your application? It would have been a very helpful context if you have included it in your question.

Comment: The lambda application sets up the pipeline for me when I chose AWS Lambda > Applications > Create Application > Author from scratch. I only modified the template.yml file. The pipeline is the default for lambda applications

Answer (score 0):

Lambda applications autogenerate a boundary policy that can only be modified through the AWS Console. The application cannot change it's own boundary for security reasons. The `Edit permissions boundary` button on the `Overview` section give instructions for updating the boundary.